# No imprime los numeros que escanea

Tags: c

El objetivo es pedir 5 numeros y cada vez que se pide uno, se muestra ese mismo. Es fácil, sin embargo no sale el resultado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int valor;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
      printf("Valor %d: ", i);
      scanf("%s", &valor);
      printf("%d\n", valor);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Lo que imprime por pantalla es:

```
Valor 1: 3
2883635 //deberia imprimir 3
Valor 2: 5
2883637 //deberia imprimir 5
Valor 3: 7
2883639 //deberia imprimir 7
Valor 4: 1
2883633 //deberia imprimir 1
Valor 5: 9
2883641 //deberia imprimir 9
```

¿Por que no imprime esos numeros?

Comment: **`"%s"`** ¿El compilador te advirtió que esto está mal? https://ideone.com/tJaBQR

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. no me lo ha advertido. Me acabo de instalar el entorno de Atom y aun no se muy bien como funciona. Sabrías como puedo poner para que me advierta de esto?

Comment: ¿Qué compilador usas? Todos los compiladores modernos advierten de tales errores. Quizás solo necesites descargar la versión actual.

Comment: instalé el paquete de gpp-compiler @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: gpp-compiler no es un compilador. Es solo un paquete de ayuda; utiliza un compilador real como mingw.

Comment: tambien lo tengo instalado @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: Necesitas añadir `-Wall -Werror` a tus opciones de compilador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia el valor en el scanf %s por %d que recoges un int como has declarado previamente. %s es para formato string.

De:

```
scanf("%s", &valor);
```

A:

```
scanf("%d", &valor);
```

Quedaría el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int valor;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
      printf("Valor %d: ", i);
      scanf("%d", &valor);
      printf("%d\n", valor);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás formateando de manera equivocada la variable en el `scanf()`, el operador `%s` sirve para formatera una cadena de carateres. Si desea escanear un valor númerico, lo adecuado es usar `%i` o bien `%d`

También es recomendable, ordenar mejor tu código, indenta y no pegues tanto las lineas.

```
scanf("%d",&valor);
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: *el main() puede ser perfectamente un void* **NO**, es falso.

Comment: dime por qué es falso?

Comment: Porque el estándar de C  dice eso. https://ideone.com/Rlt4uY

Comment: @gabrielcoronel El [estándar](http://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf) (Página 24, 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup) afirma que la forma como se debe definir el `main` es así: `int main(void) {...}`. Sin embargo, tampoco está mal definir el main de esta manera: `void main(){ ...}`, simplemente dependerá si el compilador lo permite o no (esto el estándar también lo menciona). Por cuestión de portabilidad, lo recomendable es hacer lo que dice el estándar..